# Using the word 'whither'

Tags: word-usage

Does the word **whither** mean *to where*?

Does that mean you can use it this way:

> This is the sea whither we were sailing.

> This is the city whither the ship was sailing.

> This is the island whither the crew was sailing.

Comment: It is good to know what the word means, but I would not recommend using the word today, because it is extremely old-fashioned and has been declining in usage for years: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whither&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhither%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Never let pop culture trends prevent you from expanding your vocabulary.

Comment: @barbecue Using _that_ word probably makes you to look funny... or strange XD

Comment: @barbecue I wouldn't exactly call a 200-plus-year trend "pop culture", but maybe your horizon is further than mine! :-D

Comment: @stangdon Today's pop culture is tomorrow's historical trivia.

Answer (score 20):

(The short answers to your two questions are yes, it does, and yes, you can.)

The entire sequence of the mostly archaic "adverbs of place" is:

> Whither - to where
> Hither - to here
> Thither - to there
> Whence - from where
> Hence - from here
> Thence - from there

For example, the popular song *Do you know where you're going to?* might have been *Dost thou know whither goest thou?* (reversing the last two words to make them fit rhythmically — poetic license) 300 years ago. It sounds very archaic to the native ear, though.

There are a few expressions that survive, such as *a come-hither look*, meaning a seductive look. Also, *hither and yon* (or sometimes *hither and thither* means all about chaotically with no sense of direction). And *hence* is still pretty common, but with the meaning of something that follows logically from a stated assertion: *I was in San Francisco last night, ***hence*** you could not have seen me in New York.*

[This](https://ahdictionary.tumblr.com/post/157274600693/whither-the-adverbs-of-place) is a nice summary of the words' meanings and usage. Also, [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whither%2Cwhence%2Chither%2Chence%2Cthither%2Cthence&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhither%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chither%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthither%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthence%3B%2Cc0)'s an Ngram of the frequency of the words from 1800 to the present. You can see from it that *hence* is currently used much more often than the others. (Interestingly, I find from looking over the books in this that *thence* is still in very common use in surveyors' descriptions.)

Comment: That would be "Dost thou know whither goest thou? "(or probably, goest thee) and definitely archaic (except perhaps in the hillier parts of Yorkshire)

Comment: @BrianDrummond "Dost thou know whither thou goest", surely?

Comment: @KateBunting  Agreed, too late to edit...

Comment: Re "sounds very archaic to the native ear", that really depends on the ear.  Or the eye, since it'd mostly be used in writing.  If you're writing for popular culture, probably not, but a reasonably literate audience should have no problem with it.

Comment: @KateBunting: I see your "whither thou goest", and raise you with "Knowest thou whither thou goest?"

Comment: How about 'Wost thou whither thou goest?' ('Wost' is the second-person singular of the verb 'to wit', which formerly had the meaning 'to know')

Comment: "whither thou goest, I will go" is from the Bible, Book of Ruth.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yup, it was late. That's what I meant to write. But `goest thou` instead of `thou goest` is just poetic license, to put `go` on the strong beat. I think a lot of poets do that, although I'm no Keats. As for `thee`, certainly not IMO. That would be analogous to "does he know where him is going?"

Comment: Probably from English's German roots. Modern German still uses separate words to distinguish between "where", "where-to", and "where-from".

Comment: "Hence" is used in modern English with the general meaning of "therefore", especially in technical writing. This meaning has nothing to do with physical location any more. For example "We observed X and Y in the experiment. Hence the Z hypothesis must be incorrect since it is inconsistent with X."

Comment: @alephzero or in more concrete terms: "I was in San Francisco last night, hence you could not have seen me in New York."

Comment: @fectin I was just thinking the same thing with `wohin`, `woher`, etc.

Answer (score 12):

The simple answer is, unless you are writing in the style of an 18th century poet, don't use *whither*. The word is not used in unmarked modern English.

The meaning of "whither" is "what direction" and yes, it means "to where".  So if you are sailing on a sea, from a city and to an island then the first two are wrong.  The last one is correct because it is the only one which uses a destination.

Modern Engish would use "to"

> This is the island to which the crew was sailing.

or more likely

> This is the island the crew was sailing to.

Comment: Kids of my generation were taught a rhyme that started 'Goosey goosey gander, whither  dost thou wander?" and it never did me any harm. I have seen versions with "whither shall I wander?".

Comment: Aye, my generation also.  I also read Shakespeare and Marlowe at school. But that doesn't make "Wither dost thou wander" unmarked modern English.  I agree that "whither" and "hither" would enrich the language. As would "yonder" but these are now all marked and poetic in modern use.

Comment: My mother used to say that certain women had a 'come hither' look about them, and she was by no means a student of Shakespeare and Marlowe.

Comment: I'm not sure why you assumed that the OP's first two examples were wrong, rather than referring to situations where we're sailing towards a sea or towards a city.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "come hither" or even a "come hither look/gaze" is a set phrase with its own meaning. The relationship to the meaning of "hither" is still apparent, but using and understanding that phrase doesn't require understanding "hither" itself.

Comment: @aschepler - it's archaic, not Martian. We know what "hither" means.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think you'd be surprised by how many people don't know what it means, or just think it's another way to say "here", as in "come here" (correct in the specific case, after all)

Comment: @rjpond I say "If you are going from a city to an island then..."  If you were going towards a sea or towards a city the  the answer would be different

Comment: @James K: Yonder, as in "over yonder", is fairly common use, at least in the western US.

Comment: @jamesqf Also in Southeastern US.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, ‘whither’ roughly means ‘to where’.

Historically, Germanic languages differentiated between direction and location. Some still do (you can see this in modern Swedish for example, ‘hit’ is ‘here’ as a direction, and ‘här’ is ‘here’ as a location), but English has largely lost this distinction. As a result  ‘whither’, and the equivalents ‘hither’ (to here) and ‘thither’ (to there) (and their related words ‘whence’, ‘hence’, and ‘thence’, which indicate ‘from where/here/there’) are largely archaic in modern English vernacular.

There are four places you will potentially see these words used in modern English:

- The word ‘hence’ has shifted to become a synonym with ‘therefore’ in a number of dialects, and is still used in that way.
- Historical texts, or texts emulating historical texts, obviously still use these *because* they are archaic. The shift away from whither/hither/thither/whence/hence/thence is relatively recent (compared to the age of the language as a whole), happening only within the last few centuries. As a result of how recent said shift was, a lot of people associate these words alongside a number of older pronouns (such as thee and thou) with ‘Old English’ (except it’s very much *not* Old English, it’s Early Modern English they usually end up replicating).
- Poetry will sometimes still use them. This kind of goes alongside the above point, but even when not emulating older styles these words may still find usage in poetry simply because the sound and/or rhythm may fit better.
- A small handful of idioms and fixed phrases still use them as well.

Additionally, on rare occasion, I have seen some people choose to use these words when translating from languages that do make this differentiation in cases where the difference cannot be inferred from context otherwise in English. This type of usage is uncommon to say the least though, so you are not very likely to encounter it.

Answer (score 3):

Whither is a [*locative adverb*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locative_adverb).

Note the table at the bottom of the linked wiktionary article showing the relationships between where, whither and whence on the first line. There are similar relationships between here, hither and hence, and there, thither and thence. This is one of the few instances of English being surprisingly logical.

"Where" indicates a place. "Whither" means "to that place", and "whence" means "from that place." The usage of "whither" generally indicates a question, just as "where" and "whence" do when the place is unknown.

Your examples, for instance, "This is the sea whither we were sailing" are not really in accord with correct usage. A more likely use of whither would be something like, "We are here in this sea. How did we get hither? And now whither?" Whither does mean "to where" but not as literally as you have used it in your examples.

Comment: Yes, "We are here in this sea" is what I meant, meaning a specific sea. I left a word out, sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to ELL, sovomon!

"Whither" does indeed mean "to where". Unfortunately it is now considered archaic.

Shakespeare used many similar words ('locative adverbs'):

> hence (from here), thence (from there), whence (from where);
> hither (to here), thither (to there) and whither (to where).

But although we encounter these words in literature and poetry of earlier times, we no longer use them, unless we are being deliberately archaic.

*Whom* is the only survivor, but its days are numbered!

Comment: "Hence" and (less often) "whence" are are still used, but metaphorically rather than with reference to physical space.  "Whither" survives in the set-phrase "Whither X?" (e.g. "Whither the United States?").  "Hither" survives primarily in the compound "hitherto" and also in "come-hither" as mentioned by Michael (but "come-hither" is also "old-fashioned" according to Cambridge - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-hither ).

Comment: Quite right about hence and whence. "Henceforth and thenceforth" too. Here/to/in/of/unto", "there/to/in/of/unto", "where/to/in/of" and monstrosities like "heretofor" and "hereinunder" (which I can't remember meeting in literature) all survive in legal documents. "Hither and thither" was used when I was/were a boy/lad. And it appears in a 1944 poem.

Comment: "Whom" is not "to who". It's the word "who" when it is used in objective case. If a clause substituting any other noun or pronoun as the object would use the word "to", then the version with "who" uses "to whom" or "to who"; the "to" would not be omitted.

Comment: Quite right. I was thinking of the words "to whom" and stupidly said whom *on its own* meant that! Thank you. Now deleted.